# Set wxPython widget font to external font file

Tags: python, fonts, widget, wxpython

I'm developing an application for a company that is trying to brand itself with a particular font. They've given me all the .otf files for the fonts their other products use. Is it possible to set the font on widgets such as buttons and static texts to use these external files?
If so, would it be platform-independent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but it will probably be possible soon.  I saw a patch and discussion about it recently in the wxWidgets Trac.

Comment: @DevC I believe Robin was talking about [#13568](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13568), which has not been updated for seven months now :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in this myself, and kluged something together to try it out. I looked at http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingFonts and tried the wx.TheFontList.FindOrCreateFont method to try and load the font into wxpython. This failed, as the AddFontResourceA call returned 0, which is a [failure code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); it provided no further information. THANKS MICROSOFT!!

If you install the font to the system (assuming Windows), the font selection works.

I tried this on wxpython 2.8, Windows 7 64bit and with the [Proggy fonts](http://www.proggyfonts.com/?menu=download)

```
from ctypes import *
import os

gdi32= WinDLL("gdi32.dll")
font_path = os.path.abspath("ProggySquare.tff")
print font_path
print gdi32.AddFontResourceA(font_path)

import wx
class DrawPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, event=None):
        face = "ProggySquareTT"
        prog_font = wx.TheFontList.FindOrCreateFont(28, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, False, face)
        def_font = wx.Font(12, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.SetFont(prog_font)
        dc.DrawText("Modern font Family", 50, 50)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Font Family")
DrawPanel(frame)
frame.Show()

#data = wx.FontData()
#data.EnableEffects(True)      
#dlg = wx.FontDialog(None, data)
#if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:          
#    data = dlg.GetFontData()
#    font = data.GetChosenFont() 

#e = wx.FontEnumerator()
#e.EnumerateFacenames()
#elist= e.GetFacenames()
#elist.sort()
#print elist
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: otf files are not the same as ttf, although they can sometimes be used interchangeably...